# how to read data from excel and save into database using spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i have started learning spring, please help me about how to read data from excel and save into database using spring and hibernate, please show me

Comment: You want to save file in db? or to parse it and save the content into DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not related to spring with hibernate.

To read data from excel you need to use a library like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Once you have the data in memory save them to the db using Spring with Hibernate as always (as you already tried with simple examples I hope).

Answer (score 0):

Probably in 80% of the use cases it is possible (and actually easier as no implementation is required) to export the Excel sheet as CSV and import it using common database tools. There are a lot of infos in the internet how to import CSV, e.g. [using `COPY` in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) or [`LOAD DATA` in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/).